# Is there a way to check when my Android screen was on and off?

Tags: screen

Is there a way to check when my Android screen was on and off? I am doing a medical control of when I go to sleep and when I wake up and the screen on/off is a great way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup an automation app to log those events in a file. [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid), both are capable apps that can do this.